# Maven install excluding specific modules

Tags: maven

I am installing this [project](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/nd4j.git) with several modules. The goal is to install all modules EXCEPT the `nd4j-cuda` module. If I run this:

```
mvn clean install -pl ':nd4j-cuda-8.0'
```

then maven attempts to install the module, no errors are thrown detecting it. However, since I actually do NOT want to install it, I tried

```
mvn clean install -pl '!:nd4j-cuda-8.0'
```

but I get the error message

```
Could not find the selected project in the reactor: !:nd4j-cuda-8.0
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do exactly? You don't need the `:` IIRC, just `mvn clean install -pl '!nd4j-cuda-8.0'`, run from the parent POM, and it will exclude the module having an artifact id of `nd4j-cuda-8.0`.

Comment: Without `:` it is not recognized, even if I'm trying to install only that module. E.g., `Could not find the selected project in the reactor: nd4j-cuda-8.0`

Comment: Can you post the structure of your project? Where are you running this command?

Comment: Added a link in the question. I'm running this from the parent folder. I just `git clone`, `cd` into the folder and `mvn install`

Comment: In `nd4j-backends/nd4j-backend-impls/nd4j-cuda/`

Comment: Yeah I found it. It's name is `nd4j-cuda`. I thought Maven considered the artifact id, but it could be the folder name, can you try with that?

Comment: Does not work. I'm pretty sure it's the ArtifactID

Comment: Ok so I just made a checkout of the GitHub project, and I don't have any errors when running `mvn clean install -pl '!:nd4j-cuda-8.0'` (on Windows). The project was correctly removed. So I doubled back [with the docs](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-embedder/cli.html) and you're right that it's either `:[artifactId]` (with the `:`) or `relativePath` (without the `:`). On which system are you running this command?

Comment: Linux Xubuntu. My fix was to remove those projects from the `pom.xml` and install from there. I'd still like to know why it didn't work tho

Answer (score 1):

I try with groupId:

```
mvn clean -pl '!org.nd4j:nd4j-cuda-8.0'
```

also

```
mvn clean -pl '!:nd4j-cuda-8.0'
```

give teh same result.

My maven version is: ***3.3.3***

With maven version ***3.0.5*** I have the same error as you, so please use newer version of maven.